# Using Lucene Fuzzy search with a word that has no aliases

Tags: lucene, luke

I wish do searches using fuzzy search.  Using [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to help me, if I search for a word that has aliases (eg similar words) it all works as expected:

[image: Fuzzy query with results]

However if I enter a search term that doesn't have any similar words (eg a serial code), the search fails and I get no results, even though it should be valid:

[image]

Do I need to structure my search in a different way? Why don't I get the same in the second search as the first, but with only one "term"?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified Lucene version so I would assume you are using 6.x.x. 
The behavior that you are seeing is a correct behavior of Lucene Fuzzy Search.

Refer [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) and I quote ,

> At most, this query will match terms up to 2 edits.

Which roughly but not very accurately means that two texts varying with maximum of two characters at any positions would be a returned as match if using `FuzzyQuery`.

Below is a sample output from one of my simple Java programs that I illustrate here,

> Lets say three Indexed Docs have a field with values like - 
>   "123456787"  , "123456788"  , "123456789"  ( Appended 7 , 8  and 9 to
>   – 12345678 )
>
> Results :
>
> No Hits Found for search string -> 123456  ( Edit distance = 3 , last
>   3 digits are missing)
>
> 3 Docs found !! for Search String -> 1234567  ( Edit distance = 2 )
>
> 3 Docs found !! for Search String -> 12345678 ( Edit distance = 1 )
>
> 1 Docs found !! for Search String -> 1236787  ( Edit distance = 2 for
>   found one, missing 4 , 5 and last digit for remaining two documents)
>
> No Hits Found for search string -> 123678789 ( Edit distance = 4 ,
>   missing 4 , 5 and last two digits)

So you should read more about **Edit Distance**.

If your requirement is to match N-Continuous characters without worrying about edit distance , then [N-Gram Indexing using NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html) is the way to go.

See this too for more about [N-Gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html)

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. Luke uses Lucene 3.5.